# IceFaces 3.0 java.lang.NullPointerException org.icefaces.impl.application.ExtendedExceptionHandler.handle

Tags: nullpointerexception, icefaces

I have getting following exception while running IceFaces 3.0 under Netbean 7.1.1 & Tomcat 7.0.

java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.icefaces.impl.application.ExtendedExceptionHandler.handle(ExtendedExceptionHandler.java:80)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:410)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)

A simple panelPopup used to display some information. Code is as follows

```
            <f:facet name="body">
                <ice:panelGrid width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" column="1">
                    <ice:outputText value="Here is an example of placing outputText inside a draggable panelPopup."/>
                    <ice:outputText value="Of course other components could be used as well."/>
                </ice:panelGrid>
            </f:facet>
        </ice:panelPopup>
    </ice:form>
```

i could not able to find out where is the real issue. Please help some one else to give solution, its very urgent.

Regards
Ramesh

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the HttpMonitor cause problems before so it might be worthwhile trying to turn that off when you are running from NetBeans.  Looking at the source, it seems that it can't find a FacesContext instance which would suggest that the request is not in a JSF context.  Probably going to need more information about when and how the error is occurring to provide better guidance.